# SQL cast types during copy

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting

I have a bunch of census tables in csv format that I want to bring into a postgresql database. All of the fields are strings although they represent numeric values. I tested this by creating a table with numeric types and then doing a COPY table 'myfile.csv' and got an error at the first field. When I changed the first field to VARCHAR and ran it again the error hit the second field.

Here's my statements:

```
create table race(
Id2 varchar(20),    
White numeric,  
AfAm numeric,   
NatAm numeric,  
Asian numeric,  
Hawaiin numeric, 
Other numeric,  
Inter numeric);

copy race 
FROM 'C:/Data/Waste_Intervention/Census_Tables/Cleaned/ACS_16_5YR_B02001_Race.csv'
DELIMITER ',' 
CSV
```

And here is the error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: "White"
CONTEXT:  COPY race, line 1, column white: "White"
SQL state: 22P02
```

Is there any way to convert during copy, or do I have to recast after the table is populated with varchar types

Comment: Is the first line a header row? Then you need to add the option `HEADER true`. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317353/import-csv-files-on-postgress-numeric-types

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ERROR:  syntax error at or near "TRUE"
LINE 1: ...d/ACS_16_5YR_B02001_Race.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER TRUE;

Comment: The inclusion of `HEADER` is sufficient, so you can omit `TRUE`.

Comment: @bma that works!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name was spot on with his question about the header row.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name post the answer and I'll check it